# Query to find latest code for code level in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, logic, presto

I have a table where each code id is referred to another column in the same table, following is the scenario

```
Table: Code

OldCode     NewCode
A           B
B           C
C           D
D           E
```

I want to query the above table where for `OldCode`= A the resulting code should be `NewCode`=E

i.e: `A->B`, `B->C`, `C->D`, `D->E`

I couldn't able to think of a logic in query to achieve it, but we could able to do it via `dataframe` but i want to to di via query.

I tried with CTE but i cant understand recursive CTE concept to achieve it.

Comment: What is your actual database?  You have used multiple database tags here.

Comment: We are running on Presto, the data we insert to presto is from SQL so we can do it either place, if its sql I can create different table and insert the latest code to a table to query. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a recursive CTE here:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte(n) AS (
    SELECT OldCode, NewCode, 1 AS lvl FROM yourTable WHERE OldCode = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.OldCode, t1.NewCode, n + 1
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2 ON t2.NewCode = t1.OldCode
)

SELECT NewCode
FROM cte
ORDER BY lvl DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The logic here is to join all levels together in the recursive step of the CTE (which is what appears *below* `UNION ALL`).  We also compute a level for each join, starting at 1 in the base case.  Then, to obtain the `NewCode` we want, we simply take the record with the highest level value.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @tim, if i want to query more then one record i want to run this CTE each time? it will take more time and resource?

Comment: There might be a way to handle multiple paths at once (I am not aware of that, however).  If you need to run multiple times, you could put this logic into a proc.  Also, for performance, we could look into indexing your table appropriately.